# How to make a value unique again after time passes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently, I am able to track the first instance a user logs in as unique. But I want to be able to make them unique again after 7 days, Repeating for every 7 days that passes. Is this possible with SQL?

Raw table:

| UserID | dateLogged | DayscumulativeDiff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | null |
| 1 | 01/02/2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 01/03/2022 | 2 |
| 1 | 01/04/2022 | 3 |
| 1 | 01/05/2022 | 4 |
| 1 | 01/06/2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 01/07/2022 | 6 |
| 1 | 01/08/2022 | 7 |
| 1 | 01/10/2022 | 9 |
| 1 | 01/13/2022 | 12 |
| 1 | 01/15/2022 | 14 |

Final table example

| UserID | dateLogged | IsUnique | DayscumulativeDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 01/02/2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 01/03/2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 01/04/2022 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 01/05/2022 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 01/06/2022 | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 01/07/2022 | 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 01/08/2022 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 01/10/2022 | 0 | 9 |
| 1 | 01/13/2022 | 0 | 12 |
| 1 | 01/15/2022 | 1 | 14 |
| 1 | 01/16/2022 | 0 | 15 |
| 1 | 01/28/2022 | 1 | 27 |

Comment: Sounds like you want to QUALIFY the minimum date within a one-week WINDOW of time PARTITIONED by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage a CTE with a window function to dense rank `datelogged` by userid, and `date_trunc(week,datelogged)` ordered by `datelogged` and `qualify` by 1

Then left join the CTE results back into the main table on `userid` and `datelogged`.

[Note: The day the week starts is a parameter in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-week-start). So make sure it is set for what you consider the first day of the week (eg. Sun is first, or Mon is first.)

```
create or replace table logins(userid int, datelogged date);

INSERT INTO logins(UserID, dateLogged) 
VALUES(1, '01/01/2022')
,(1, '01/02/2022')
,(1, '01/03/2022')
,(1, '01/04/2022')
,(1, '01/05/2022')
,(1, '01/06/2022')
,(1, '01/07/2022')
,(1, '01/08/2022')
,(1, '01/10/2022')
,(1, '01/13/2022')
,(1, '01/15/2022');

alter session set WEEK_START = 7; -- Sunday is the first day (this can be set at an account level as well. 

-- create a cte to dense rank datelogged by userid, and week 
-- qualify by 1 (fist instance of login )
with week_first_login as (
select 
      userid
    , datelogged
    , dense_rank() over (partition by userID, date_trunc(week,datelogged) order by datelogged asc) as IsUnique
from logins
qualify IsUnique = 1)
select
      l.userid
    , l.datelogged
    , dayname(l.datelogged) as day_name
    , nvl(wfl.IsUnique,0) as IsUnique
from logins l
    left join week_first_login wfl
        on l.userid = wfl.userid
            and l.datelogged = wfl.datelogged
order by userid, datelogged asc;
```

Result:

| USERID | DATELOGGED | DAY_NAME | ISUNIQUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | Sat | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | Sun | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | Mon | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | Tue | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | Wed | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | Thu | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-07 | Fri | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-08 | Sat | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-10 | Mon | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-13 | Thu | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 | Sat | 0 |